# What is the meaning of "нигде так не любят русских туристов как нигде"

Tags: значения

There are way too many negations for me to grasp the meaning of this phrase:

- нигде так не любят русских туристов как нигде

Comment: This is a slightly clumsy pun, literally meaning 'Nowhere Russian tourists are liked as much as nowhere', implying that no place exists where they are liked at all

Comment: I'd rather say it stupid pun, slightly clumsy is too kind)

Comment: I consider it an OK joke. Not spectacular, but still moderately amusing. Just to add a data point to our collection of valuable opinions.

Comment: "Как нигде" is incorrect form (intentional error is part of a joke here). Look at my answer about words like "нигде" [there](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/why-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bca%d1%8e-isnt-%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bca%d1%8e-enough).

Answer (score 16):

**Short:** the meaning is "Nobody loves Russian tourists".

**Long**

This is a humoristically paradoxical sentence.

Let's replace the last word:

> Нигде так не любят русских туристов, как в Париже.

This one is quite simple: *Nowhere are Russian tourists loved as much as in Paris*. The first part implies that Russian tourists are loved everywhere, and the ending says that while they are loved everywhere, in Paris they are loved even more.

Now, looking at the original sentence: *Nowhere are Russian tourists loved as much as nowhere.*

It is a standard construction and is used quite often:

> Нигде я не чувствую себя так хорошо, как в горах - Nowhere do I feel as good as in the mountains.
>
> Никуда я не ездил так часто, как на море - Nowhere have I traveled as often as to the sea.
>
> Никто тебя не любит так, как я - No one loves you as much as I do.